# Layout breaks when image is missing

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have the following piece of `html` code:

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h2><a href='#'>WALL-E Review</a></h2>
                    <img src='images/featured01.jpg' alt="WALL-E">
                </header>
            <time datetime="2011-10-10"> 10 Octomber 2011 </time>
            <p>What if mankind had to leave Earth, and somebody forgot to turn the last robot off?</p>
            </article>
        </li>
        <li>
           //contains another <article> similar to the first one
        </li>
        <li>
           //contains another <article> similar to the first one
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I have to style this `html` code without changing it using `css` only so that the three articles appear next to each other. The `<img>` elements should be above the `<time>` elements and `<time>` elements should be above the `<p>` elements. Something like this: [with image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5AXSi-pHepGRl9EblZ4SWRxSUk/view?usp=sharing). If an image is missing though it looks like this: [without image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5AXSi-pHepGYmJiekR3eEtpLWM/view?usp=sharing).

Here is the simplified version of the `css` I use to style it and where I think I go wrong:

```
    li {
        float: left;
        //some padding
    }

    time {
        position: relative;
        top: 8px;
    }

    p {
        position: relative;
        top: 16px;
    }
```

Can you help me fix it so that the time and the description always appear at the same place even when the image is missing?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the breakage?  I am not clear exactly on how it is "broken"

Comment: [here you go](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5AXSi-pHepGYmJiekR3eEtpLWM/view?usp=sharing). When there is no image I want the text to appear where it appears when there is image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the header area has height:

`height:200px` - or something similar:

`header  { height: 200px; }`

`img` will need to have same height or it will look like it is staggering - the white space will then appear inplace of an image.

also, to prevent text from appearing above the time area, consider using this: (it may be a little overkill)

```
li {   /* avoid using float:left as it can adversely effect other DOM elements */
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
}
li header {    /* ensure header contains image and is the same size */
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li header > img {  /* ensure image fits in header */
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to position your elements absolute instead of relative? This will cause a independency of the position of all objects.

I like the design of you webpage, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

How are you ensuring that your image dimensions are the same?
Perhaps using a div with preset dimensions such as width:200px; height:200px;. Then if there is nothing in that div, it is still styled in the same original location but would be blank.

You might consider:

```
<div></div>

div {
width:200px;
height:200px;
position:relative;
float:left;
}
```

This way you could use the div as a sort of placeholder and also as a spot that you could slap an image in whenever you wanted.

Comment: Thank you! I had width and height for the images but I thought it was irrelevant for the question and skipped it in the description. I added just `float: left` as you suggested and it fixed it!

Comment: float should be avoided if at all possible